# How to install older R version on CentOS

Tags: r, centos

The installed version is 3.3.0.

I would like to install version 2.X but I don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you building from the tar.gz file? If so, you should be able to download any version you like, here's a folder with the files for 2.x versions:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/

EDIT to add:

You can try installing like so, in your shell terminal. (this should work in, for example, Debian, but please read on for the OP's solution in CentOS).

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/R-2.15.3.tar.gz
tar zxvf R-2.15.3.tar.gz; cd R-2.15.3/ 
./configure; make; sudo make install
```

**ADDED from OP, who found a CentOS solution**:

Thanks to @resscova's answer and some research on the net. Here's how to install R-2.X.tar.gz on Centos :

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install ncurses-devel zlib-devel texinfo gtk+-devel gtk2-devel qt-devel tcl-devel tk-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel
./configure --with-x=no
make
make install
```

Comment: I don't know how to install a tar.gz program on Centos. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I've added a guide to install from tar.gz you can try.

Comment: I don't know how yum works or who maintains it, but man it would be awesome to enable something like: 'sudo yum install R -v 3.5.3'

Answer (score 4):

I installed R-3.3.3 with sources - https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.3.3.tar.gz on CENTOS 7 after xlsx library stops working with R-3.4.1

These are the steps I took for successful Installation of R 3.3.3

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.3.3.tar.gz
tar xvzf R-3.3.3.tar.gz
cd R-3.3.3
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install ncurses-devel zlib-devel texinfo gtk+-devel gtk2-devel qt-devel tcl-devel tk-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel readline-devel

./configure --with-x=no 
make
sudo make install
```

Make sure to install readline-devel otherwie you may have to use --with-readline=no while configuring make file.

Comment: You need to install libcurl-devel on centos before ./configure i.e. yum install -y libcurl-devel

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @resscova's answer and some research on the net. Here's one way install R-2.X.tar.gz on Centos:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install ncurses-devel zlib-devel texinfo gtk+-devel gtk2-devel qt-devel tcl-devel tk-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel
./configure --with-x=no
make
make install
```

Comment: Excellent! I've added your solution to the accepted answer, so others can find it easily should they have the same issue.